# Research between different campuses of the same university

Tags: research-process, tenure-track, collaboration, academic-life

I was recently applying for a tenure track position at a university.  I had found people who had adjacent research interests, and thought it would be good to mention them as possible collaborators for research.  However, I just found out that these researchers work at a different, smaller campus under the same university structure.

How common is collaboration between different campuses of the same university? To clarify, in my case,this isn't a state university either (for example,university of X- cityA vs university of X- cityB... these do tend to feel more like separate universities altogether), but rather a private university with various campuses and satellite locations. I'm sure that this is dependent on the university culture, but I wanted to see if anyone had any experience with this.

Comment: I don't think any generalization is possible.

Comment: Well how far are they?

Comment: It's pretty common also, at least in my field, for people to collaborate between institutions, even those located on different continents.

Comment: Some questions you could try to find the answers to: (1) Do, in fact, researchers in this department collaborate with those at the smaller campus? See if you can match up research interests and look up their lists of papers. (2) Can you find other evidence that researchers at the smaller campus engage with the main campus? For example, do any have links to its seminar or colloquium schedules on their webpages? Or do they give talks at the main campus? Do any of them claim to have advised students at the main campus? etc. etc. etc. Would take some googling, but that probably can't be helped.

Comment: Also, reading Vladhagen's answer: looking up grant databases, e.g. from the NSF, can you find any grants with faculty from the satellite campus as co-PI, or vice versa?

Comment: Not what you asked, but I would really consider whether it makes sense to list "possible collaborators for research" at all. To me, empty statements like "Bob's research is interesting; I might try to work with Bob" only underscore that you have no _actual_ plans. Prospective grad students can get away with statements like that (they're not expected to know many people), but at your level, if you list collaboration with someone in your job docs, I expect that you actually know them and have discussed possible collaboration. (But of course, academia is a big place, so your mileage may vary).

Comment: @cag51, I am currently a PhD student who is now on the job market, so while I do have a network of people through my advisor, it's still not quite large yet.  the university isn't R1 and the people hired there come from my tier institution or lower, most without postdocs, so I might have more of a chance.

Comment: @AzorAhai, the campuses are located at opposite ends of the US, though the one I'm applying to has a big online presence.

Comment: @academic  both researchers are also somewhat new.  Their main collaborators seem to be previous advisors and people from their older institutions.

Answer (score 1):

With the growing prevalence of networking technology, collaboration is easier than it ever has been before. I would think that collaboration across two campuses of the same university would be even easier. It is very probable that funding and resources can be more easily shared and that graduate students will have even an easier time working in such collaboration. I see nothing that would impede collaboration here.

I have worked with a national lab (which, although not a university, can at least somewhat resemble academia a little bit) that had two locations. We collaborated commonly between campuses. It made funding considerations quite simple and we produced quality research.